# Create XML file using java

Tags: java, xml

How to create a xml file and save it in some place in my machine using java..there are attributes also include in the xml file? I have found org.w3c.dom.Document but having problems with creating attributes for elements and save the xml file.

Thank You.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a DOM XML parser to create an XML file using Java. A good  example can be found [on this site](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/):

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    //root elements
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    //staff elements
    Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
    rootElement.appendChild(staff);

    //set attribute to staff element
    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
    attr.setValue("1");
    staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

    //shorten way
    //staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

    //firstname elements
    Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
    firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
    staff.appendChild(firstname);

    //lastname elements
    Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
    lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mook kim"));
    staff.appendChild(lastname);

    //nickname elements
    Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
    nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mkyong"));
    staff.appendChild(nickname);

    //salary elements
    Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
    salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
    staff.appendChild(salary);

    //write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory =  TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

    StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File("C:\\testing.xml"));
    transformer.transform(source, result);

    System.out.println("Done");

}catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
    pce.printStackTrace();
}catch(TransformerException tfe){
    tfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What does the xml `String` look like? Please include before the code.

Comment: -1 for not acknowledging source, which implies it is original material

Comment: I thought that todofixthis's "Pretty code" comment was sarcasm, this being Java's standard XML API and all, so I upvoted it. :)

Comment: answer with explanation is present here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50148098/9339242

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Xembly](https://github.com/yegor256/xembly), a small open source library that makes this XML creating process much more intuitive:

```
String xml = new Xembler(
  new Directives()
    .add("root")
    .add("order")
    .attr("id", "553")
    .set("$140.00")
).xml();
```

Xembly is a wrapper around native Java DOM, and is a very lightweight library (I'm the author).

Comment: @DanielAbouChleih, I came here after _4 years_ and found this answer useful.

Answer (score 3):

Have look at [**dom4j**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dom4j/) or [**jdom**](http://www.jdom.org/). Both libraries allow creating a Document and allow printing the document as xml. Both are widly used, pretty easy to use and you'll find a lot of examples and snippets.

[dom4j - Quick start guide](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just happened to work at this also, use https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_create_document.htm the example from here, and read the explanations. Also I provide you my own example:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
        // root element


Element rootElement = doc.createElement("words");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);
while (ptbt.hasNext()) {
                CoreLabel label = ptbt.next();
                System.out.println(label);

                m = r1.matcher(label.toString());
                //System.out.println(m.find());
                if (m.find() == true) {
                    Element w = doc.createElement("word");                  
                    w.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(label.toString()));
                    rootElement.appendChild(w);
                }

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\workspace\\Tokenizer\\tokens.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        // Output to console for testing
        StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, consoleResult);
```

This is in the context of using the tokenizer from Stanford for Natural Language Processing, just a part of it to make an idea on how to add elements.
The output is: Billbuyedapples (I've read the sentence from a file)

Answer (score 2):

I am providing an answer from my own [blog](https://interviewbubble.com/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-using-dom-parser-java-xml-tutorial/). Hope this will help.

**What will be output?**

Following XML file named users.xml will be created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?> 
<users>
    <user uid="1">
        <firstname>Interview</firstname>
        <lastname>Bubble</lastname>
        <email>admin@interviewBubble.com</email>
    </user>
</users>
```

**PROCEDURE**

Basic steps, in order to create an XML File with a DOM Parser, are:

1. Create a `DocumentBuilder` instance.
2. Create a Document from the above `DocumentBuilder`.
3. Create the elements you want using the `Element` class and its `appendChild` method.
4. Create a new `Transformer` instance and a new `DOMSource` instance.
5. Create a new `StreamResult` to the output stream you want to use.
6. Use `transform` method to write the DOM object to the output stream.

**SOURCE CODE:**

```
package com.example.TestApp;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class CreateXMLFileJava {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, 
                                               IOException, 
                                               TransformerException
    {
     // 1.Create a DocumentBuilder instance
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dbuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // 2. Create a Document from the above DocumentBuilder.
    Document document = dbuilder.newDocument();

    // 3. Create the elements you want using the Element class and its appendChild method.   

   // root element
    Element users = document.createElement("users");
    document.appendChild(users);   

    // child element
    Element user = document.createElement("user");
    users.appendChild(user);  

    // Attribute of child element
    user.setAttribute("uid", "1");   

    // firstname Element
    Element firstName = document.createElement("firstName");
    firstName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Interview"));
    user.appendChild(firstName);   

    // lastName element
    Element lastName = document.createElement("lastName");
    lastName.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Bubble"));
    user.appendChild(lastName);   

    // email element
    Element email = document.createElement("email");
    email.appendChild(document.createTextNode("admin@interviewBubble.com"));
    user.appendChild(email);   

    // write content into xml file   

    // 4. Create a new Transformer instance and a new DOMSource instance.
   TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
   DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

   // 5. Create a new StreamResult to the output stream you want to use.
   StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/Users/admin/Desktop/users.xml"));
   // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out); // to print on console

   // 6. Use transform method to write the DOM object to the output stream.
   transformer.transform(source, result);  

   System.out.println("File created successfully");
 }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<users>
  <user uid="1">
     <firstName>Interview</firstName>
     <lastName>Bubble</lastName>
     <email>admin@interviewBubble.com</email>
  </user>
</users>
```

Comment: so , where to set the `encoding="UTF-8"`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io) a shot, it is not complicated. It basically does the heavy lifting.

Comment: This URL requires a username/password.

Comment: @james.garriss: Link amended.

Comment: "XStream is a simple library to serialize objects to XML and back again."

Answer (score 0):

I liked the Xembly syntax, but it is not a statically typed API. You can get this with [XMLBeam](http://xmlbeam.org):

```
// Declare a projection
public interface Projection {

    @XBWrite("/root/order/@id")
    Projection setID(int id);

    @XBWrite("/root/order")
    Projection setValue(String value);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a projector
    XBProjector projector = new XBProjector();

    // use it to create a projection instance
    Projection projection = projector.projectEmptyDocument(Projection.class);

    // You get a fluent API, with java types in parameters 
    projection.setID(553).setValue("$140.00");

    // Use the projector again to do IO stuff or create an XML-string
    projector.toXMLString(projection);
}
```

My experience is that this works great even when the XML gets more complicated. You can just decouple the XML structure from your java code structure.

Answer (score -4):

```
package com.server;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import org.w3c.dom.*;

import com.gwtext.client.data.XmlReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;  

public class XmlServlet extends HttpServlet
{ 

  NodeList list;
  Connection con=null;
  Statement st=null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  String xmlString ;
  BufferedWriter bw;
  String displayTo;
  String displayFrom;
  String addressto;
  String addressFrom;
  Date send;
  String Subject;
  String body;
  String category;
  Document doc1;
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException,IOException{

    System.out.print("on server");  

  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
  System.out.print("on server");
  try
  {


    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    //creating a new instance of a DOM to build a DOM tree.
    doc1 = docBuilder.newDocument();
    new XmlServlet().createXmlTree(doc1);

    System.out.print("on server");

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
  System.out.println(e.toString());
  }

   }

  public void createXmlTree(Document doc) throws Exception {
  //This method creates an element node

    System.out.println("ruchipaliwal111");

    try
    {

      System.out.println("ruchi111");
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/plz","root","root1");
      st = con.createStatement();

      rs = st.executeQuery("select * from data");


      Element root = doc.createElement("message");
      doc.appendChild(root);

        while(rs.next())
        {



       displayTo=rs.getString(1).toString();
       System.out.println(displayTo+"getdataname");

       displayFrom=rs.getString(2).toString();
       System.out.println(displayFrom +"getdataname");

         addressto=rs.getString(3).toString();
         System.out.println(addressto +"getdataname");

       addressFrom=rs.getString(4).toString();
       System.out.println(addressFrom +"getdataname");

       send=rs.getDate(5);
       System.out.println(send +"getdataname");

       Subject=rs.getString(6).toString();
       System.out.println(Subject +"getdataname");

       body=rs.getString(7).toString();
       System.out.println(body+"getdataname");

      category=rs.getString(8).toString();
       System.out.println(category +"getdataname");


       //adding a node after the last child node of ssthe specified node.


        Element element1 = doc.createElement("Header");
        root.appendChild(element1);


        Element child1 = doc.createElement("To");
        element1.appendChild(child1);

        child1.setAttribute("displayNameTo",displayTo);
        child1.setAttribute("addressTo",addressto);

        Element child2 = doc.createElement("From");
        element1.appendChild(child2);

        child2.setAttribute("displayNameFrom",displayFrom);
        child2.setAttribute("addressFrom",addressFrom);

        Element child3 = doc.createElement("Send");
        element1.appendChild(child3);

        Text text2 = doc.createTextNode(send.toString());
        child3.appendChild(text2);

        Element child4 = doc.createElement("Subject");
        element1.appendChild(child4);

        Text text3 = doc.createTextNode(Subject);
        child4.appendChild(text3);

        Element child5 = doc.createElement("category");
        element1.appendChild(child5);

        Text text44 = doc.createTextNode(category);
        child5.appendChild(text44);


        Element element2 = doc.createElement("Body");
        root.appendChild(element2);

        Text text1 = doc.createTextNode(body);
        element2.appendChild(text1);

       /*
        Element child1 = doc.createElement("name");
        root.appendChild(child1);
        Text text = doc.createTextNode(getdataname);
        child1.appendChild(text);
        Element element = doc.createElement("address");
        root.appendChild(element);
        Text text1 = doc.createTextNode( getdataaddress);
        element.appendChild(text1); 
     */
      } 






//TransformerFactory instance is used to create Transformer objects. 
  TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD,"xml");
  // transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "3");


  // create string from xml tree
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
  transformer.transform(source, result);

  xmlString = sw.toString();


  File file = new File("./war/ds/newxml.xml");
  bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file)));
  bw.write(xmlString);
   }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.print("after while loop exception"+e.toString());
    }

  bw.flush();
  bw.close();
  System.out.println("successfully done.....");
  }
}
```

Comment: What the heck does SQL have to do with this??

Comment: What the heck do Servlets have to do with this?