# Is there a simple way to create xml in Java as compared to creating JSON

Tags: java, xml, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create XML file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142046/create-xml-file-using-java)

In Java to create the JSONObject `{"box":"tissue","desk":"wood"}` all I need to do is

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("box","tissue");
json.put("desk","wood");
```

And to create the JSONObject `{"my-stuff":{"box":"tissue","desk":"wood"}}` all I need to do is

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("box","tissue");
json.put("desk","wood");

JSONObject myStuff = new JSONObject();
myStuff.put("my-stuff",json);
```

Then to get the `String` representations back, I just do `json.toString()` or `myStuff.toString()`.

I happen to be using `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;` but really that's how JSONObject works.

Is there an equivalently simple way to create XML in Java? If not, still, what's the simplest way to do what I just did -- in XML?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4142046/411871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest [Dom4J](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/):

```
Element root = DocumentHelper.createElement("my-stuff")
Document dom = DocumentHelper.createDocument(root);
root.addElement("box").setText("tissue");
System.out.println(dom.asXml());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. `setContent` is expecting a list not a string. I am following the link. It has some examples. But I am still not sure how to get `<my-stuff><box>tissue</box><desk>wood</desk></my-stuff>`.

Comment: @kasavbere it's setText, not setContent, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Surely there is, but if you already have a bunch of json code written anyways, **I would suggest simply turning your json into xml**, like this: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/279-how-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-java/

I apologize for not answering your question directly, but unless you've implemented a serialization wrapper, just turning the json into xml is going to save a ton of development time (as opposed to duplicating every line of code where you're adding/pulling from your json objects or - as I alluded to earlier - implementing a serialization wrapper).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestiong. I am confident someone will find it useful. But I don't have json objects.

Comment: I think this is very useful when you have JSON objects. On the other hand, @kasavbere, I think you can produce your JSONObjects and JSONArrays first, just like you explained on your question, then you can convert them to XML.

Comment: That's a great thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)? If you have a well modeled class, then its trivial to generate the xml as a string.  You can also customize the output by using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check out Groovy (which is compatible with Java), and it's MarkupBuilder. For an example, see  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-pg05199/