# Create XML on JAVA

Tags: java, xml

I need to create an XML on JAVA but for multi fields on one element:

```
<cities>
  <city_insert city_id="123" city_name="São Paulo" />
  <city_insert city_id="456" city_name="Rio de Janeiro"/>
</cities>
```

As you can see on the example above, the element city_insert need to have `city_id`, and `city_name` ,  one element can have multiples fields.

How this can be done on `Java`?
I've searched for **DOM** and **JDOM** parsers but still don't know how this works.

Thank you!

Comment: you are in the right track... DOM can be done pretty straight forward....

Comment: what is wrong with straight string concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this question for creating an XML using DOM parser.

[Create XML file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142046/create-xml-file-using-java)

In order to create an attribute (which you mentioned as fields), call setAttribute() method.

```
nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("city_insert");
for (Element element : nodelist) {
   Element parent = element.getParentNode()
   parent.setAttribute("city_id", "123");
   parent.setAttribute("city_name", "São Paulo");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I allways do this things using `jaxb`

First, generate an xsd from your xml (there are many free online generators on the net)

For your xml, an online generated xsd look as follows:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="cities">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="city_insert" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="city_id" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="city_name" use="optional"/>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then, using jaxb (many IDE's like Eclipse have an easy way of doing it) generate jaxb classes from an xsd:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Click finish, then this is java console output:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
com\erax\xml\test\xsd\Cities.java
com\erax\xml\test\xsd\ObjectFactory.java
```

And the generated classes:

[image]

Then just use jaxb marshalling to serialize and deserialize

Comment: Wow! i didn't know about that too, Thank you for the help! Have a nice week!