# How implementation integration best practices?

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot

I’m planning to create module name **PaymentIntegration** will be as integration between **cheques system** and **bank side** the aim this project to generate **XML file** depends on the request type there basically two types

1-  Payment Initiation (pain.008)

2-  Payments Clearing and Settlement (pacs.003)

example :

https://github.com/salesking/sepa_king/blob/master/spec/examples/pain.008.003.02.xml
https://www.iso20022.org/sites/default/files/documents/messages/pacs/schemas/pacs.003.001.07.xsd

I ‘didn’t find any Java API to generate like these XML , there any suggest to start implementation this project also I will development using spring boot framework

**i don't know if this correct place to ask here , if there are any suggest please advice**

Answer (score 1):

You can find many examples of how to [create xml using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142046/create-xml-file-using-java) on SO.

Moreover, for more complex structures like this, I would recommend some templating engine like [freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/)